# Where can I report a bug in erratic_gazebo_plugins?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

as I have problems with multi-robot simulations using the diffdriveplugin I would like to report a bug resp. discuss about this problem with the developers. How can I do this?

Regards,
Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11863/where-can-i-report-a-bug-in-erratic_gazebo_plugins?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sabrina, you can report bugs at ua-ros-pkg [issue tracker page](http://code.google.com/p/ua-ros-pkg/issues/list) or send me an email to discuss (email is on my webpage linked from here).

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-11-09**:
I posted it on the issue tracker.